# OpenID & OAuth : Best Authorization Grant Type approach to get Access & Identity tokens with Customized Login screen

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, openid, thinktecture-ident-server, openid-connect

Currently we are using Authorization Code Grant to achieve both Authentication and Authorization token using Thinktecture Identity Server.

Now the login screen is part of the identity Server. But we need to have our own login screen in our client application instead of having an identity server login page in Server.

But still we need to get Authentication and Authorization token from Thinktecture Identity Server.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Authorization code flow grant which provides access token and id token

Comment: yes. we have implemented Authorization code grant. but Login page placed in Thinktecture Identity Server. I want to have my own login page out side Identity Server/ inside In my web client.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible. But you can customize the identity server login screen to fit your branding as follows. http://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/advanced/customizingViews.html

Also if you are concerns with the login URL, you might consider hosting identity server on the same host as your client.
http://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html